# SimpleXML returns empty arrays

Tags: php, google-maps, simplexml

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of a city with the Google Maps API and through PHP (SimpleXML).

I try to do it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Brussels,Belgium&sensor=false");
$lat= $xml->xpath("lat");
print_r($lat);
```

But this returns an empty array every time.
Am I missing something?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for a particular `lat` do this:

```
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Brussels,Belgium&sensor=false");
  $lat= $xml->xpath("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat");
  print_r($lat);
?>
```

For all `lat` occurrences specify the path of `//lat`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this instead:

```
$xml->xpath("//lat");
```

In this way you're searching for lat tag which could be everywhere in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Your [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) query is wrong.  It should be:

```
$lat= $xml->xpath("//lat");
```

The `//` tells xPath to search for `lat` nodes no matter where they are.